# Scrolling Card in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

What I am trying to achieve is to have both boxes be equal width, that is the size of the card on the left (with the image) is always the max width of the card on the right with the list box.

The desired outcome would be then an equal width, with a scroll bar for the clipped content of the left card.

I have attempted overflow CSS properties, however they never result in a functioning scrolling bar. I would specify a height in pixels for the list card, and a scrollbar would appear however they would not match height of the left card.

You may view my example below fullscreen, as the problem exists for non-mobile views.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid pt-1 pb-1" style="background: #eeeeee">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <h2 class="text-center h2-special-gray text-center" style="color: #444!important; font-family: 'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif; padding-top:15px;">Meetings unlike any other</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid pt-4 pb-5">
    <div class="row mx-lg-2 mx-sm-0">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 d-flex">
        <div class="card">
          <a href="my link here">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="https://place-hold.it/300x100/666/fff/000.gif" alt="Card image cap">
          </a>
          <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill navtop">
            <li class="nav-item px-sm-0">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="my link/">WELCOME</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">
              <span class="lead">Here I am begin example</span> text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext
              text texttext text texttext text texttext text text
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12  d-flex ">
        <div class="card w-100">
          <div class="card-body" style="padding-left: 0!important; padding-right: 0!important; padding-top: 0!important;">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill navtop">
              <li class="nav-item px-sm-0">
                <a class="nav-link active text-left" href="https://meetings.cshl.edu/">UPCOMING EVENTS</a>
              </li>
            </ul>

            <div class="position-absolute all-0 d-flex flex-column">
              <ul class="list-group list-group-hover d-flex overflow-auto" style="overflow-y: auto;">

                <li class="list-group-item w-100">
                  <a id="event1" class="lead" href="link">Specific Event Name</a>
                  <br>
                  <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> Mon Mar 11 - Sun Mar 17 2019
                  <span id="" class="text-muted"></span>
                  <br>
                  <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Applications - Tue Jan 15 2019
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item w-100">
                  <a id="event1" class="lead" href="link">Specific Event Name</a>
                  <br>
                  <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> Mon Mar 11 - Sun Mar 17 2019
                  <span id="" class="text-muted"></span>
                  <br>
                  <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Applications - Tue Jan 15 2019
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item w-100">
                  <a id="event1" class="lead" href="link">Specific Event Name</a>
                  <br>
                  <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> Mon Mar 11 - Sun Mar 17 2019
                  <span id="" class="text-muted"></span>
                  <br>
                  <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Applications - Tue Jan 15 2019
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item w-100">
                  <a id="event1" class="lead" href="link">Specific Event Name</a>
                  <br>
                  <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> Mon Mar 11 - Sun Mar 17 2019
                  <span id="" class="text-muted"></span>
                  <br>
                  <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Applications - Tue Jan 15 2019
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item w-100">
                  <a id="event1" class="lead" href="link">Specific Event Name</a>
                  <br>
                  <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> Mon Mar 11 - Sun Mar 17 2019
                  <span id="" class="text-muted"></span>
                  <br>
                  <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Applications - Tue Jan 15 2019
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item w-100">
                  <a id="event1" class="lead" href="link">Specific Event Name</a>
                  <br>
                  <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> Mon Mar 11 - Sun Mar 17 2019
                  <span id="" class="text-muted"></span>
                  <br>
                  <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Applications - Tue Jan 15 2019
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="sidebar_item">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was able to solve this by adding a bootstrap utility class 'h-100' on the following
line,
 
`<div class="position-absolute all-0 d-flex flex-column w-100 h-100">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by adding a bootstrap utility class 'h-100' on the following line,

```
<div class="position-absolute all-0 d-flex flex-column w-100 h-100">
```